# Get the 3 max value in a Map

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm storing information of the `lastByFirst` variable.

```
{Peter=[Leigh], George=[Barron, Trickett,Evans], 
 Paul-Courtenay=[Hyu], Ryan=[Smith], Toby=[Geller, Williams], 
 Simon=[Bush, Milosic, Quarterman,Brown]}
```

How can I print the first `3` which appeared the most and also the number of appereance.

I would like to list those which 3 value appeared the most. In the `lastByFirst` contains something like that. I would like to print in this way:

```
Simon: 4  
George: 3  
Toby:2
```

```
Map<String, List<String>> lastByFirst = PeopleProcessor.lastnamesByFirstname(PeopleSetup.people);
```

My attempt was something like that:

```
var store = lastByFirst.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getLastName,
                Collectors.counting())
    .toString();
```

`store` should be equal with

```
Simon: 4  
George: 3  
Toby:2
```

Comment: Tags doesnt look correct. Is this java  ?

Comment: @AbhishekSingh Why would it not be Java

Comment: This seems like an XY-problem, not to mention that Map of yours, a most unnecessary construct. Please tell us what you actually need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one that first converts the map of lists to a map of the sizes of the list, and then picks the top three such sizes:

```java
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> lastByFirst =
            Map.of("Peter", List.of("Leigh"), "George", List.of("Barron", "Trickett", "Evans"),
                   "Paul-Courtenay", List.of("Hyu"), "Ryan", List.of("Smith"),
                   "Toby", List.of("Geller", "Williams"), "Simon", List.of("Bush", "Milosic", "Quaterman", "Brown"));
        List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> topThree =
            lastByFirst.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toUnmodifiableMap(Map.Entry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().size()))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.<Map.Entry<String, Integer>, Integer>comparing(Map.Entry::getValue).reversed())
            .limit(3)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(topThree);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. sort in descending mode by size
2. select the first three elements
3. reduce to one string

```java
//1
List<Map.Entry<String, List<String>>> entryList = lastByFirst.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .sorted((e2, e1) -> Integer.compare(e1.getValue().size(), e2.getValue().size()))
        .toList();
//2
String result = IntStream.range(0, 3)
        .mapToObj(entryList::get)
        .map(e -> String.format("%s: %d\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue().size()))
        .collect(Collectors.joining()); //3
```

Comment: thanks but the output should be:
Simon: 4  
George: 3  
Toby:2

and when I run my code the output is not like that

Comment: Don’t let using something like `reduce(String::concat)` become a habit. Use `collect(Collectors.joining())` instead. Further, `String.format("%s: %d\n", e.getKey(), e.getValue().size())` offers no advantage over a straight-forward `e.getKey() + ": " + e.getValue().size() + "\n"`

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a map of people grouped by *first name*, you can address the problem of finding the `3` most frequent *first names* in a linear time **O(n)**. Which is faster than sorting the whole data set.

If instead of picking `3` most frequent *first names* it would be generalized to `m` most frequent, then the time complexity would be **O(n + m * log m)** (*which for small values of `m` would be close to linear time*).

To implement it using streams, we can utilize a *custom comparator*, which can be created using the static method [`Collector.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...)).

As a *mutable container* of the collector, we can use a `TreeMap` sorted in the *natural order*, where the *key* would represent the of people having the same first name and the *value* would be a first name itself.

In order to retain only `m` most frequent names we need to track the size of the `TreeMap` and when it gets exceeded we have to remove the *first entry* (i.e. an entry having the *lowest key*).

```
public static <K, V> Collector<Map.Entry<K, List<V>>, ?, NavigableMap<Integer, K>>
                                                        getEntryCollector(int size) {
    return Collector.of(
        TreeMap::new,
        (NavigableMap<Integer, K> map, Map.Entry<K, List<V>> entry) -> {
            if (map.size() < size || map.firstKey() < entry.getValue().size()) {  // the container hasn't reached the maximum size of the frequency of the offered name is higher than the lowest existing frequency
                map.put(entry.getValue().size(), entry.getKey());
            }
            if (map.size() > size) map.remove(map.firstKey()); // the size of the container has been exceeded
        },
        (NavigableMap<Integer, K> left, NavigableMap<Integer, K> right) -> { // merging the two containers with partial results obtained during the parallel execution
            left.putAll(right);
            while (left.size() > size) left.remove(left.firstKey());
            return left;
        }
    );
}
```

`main()`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Map<String, List<String>> lastByFirst =
    Map.of("Peter", List.of("Leigh"), "George", List.of("Barron", "Trickett", "Evans"),
    "Paul-Courtenay", List.of("Hyu"), "Ryan", List.of("Smith"), "Toby", List.of("Geller", "Williams"),
    "Simon", List.of("Bush", "Milosic", "Quarterman", "Brown"));

    NavigableMap<Integer, String> nameByFrequency =
        lastByFirst.entrySet().stream()
            .collect(getEntryCollector(3));
    
    nameByFrequency.entrySet().stream() // printing the result, sorting in reversed order applied only for demo purposes
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByKey(Comparator.<Integer>naturalOrder().reversed()))
        .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getValue() + ": " + entry.getKey()));
}
```

*Output:*

```
Simon: 4
George: 3
Toby: 2
```

[*A link Online Demo*](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/sfz)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex):

```
EntryStream.of(lastByFirst)
        .mapValues(List::size) //
        .reverseSorted(Comparators.comparingByValue())
        .limit(3)
        .toList()
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```